# android image rotate x axis

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I have found a lot of solutoins how to rotate image relatively to point like whis. 
[image]

But I need rotate image relatively to x axis, like this.
[image]

Any help appreciate.

Comment: use a Matrix to modify your ImageView, the easiest way to create that Matrix is Matrix.polyToPoly method or you can use android. graphics.Camera class

Comment: Can you show the code example? I have never used this method.

Comment: sorry it should have been setPolyToPoly for example http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-4/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/PolyToPoly.java.shtml

Comment: BTW if you support just 4+ devices use setRotationX :)

Comment: unfortunatelly I support devices 2.3+

Comment: setPolyToPoly() works for me. Thx

Comment: не за что, пожалуйста

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
  ImageView imageView;   
    Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();   
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);  

    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(  
    R.drawable.icon_150_380882090)).getBitmap();  

    Camera camera = new Camera();  
    camera.save();  
    camera.rotateY(50f);  
    //camera.rotateX(50f);  
    //camera.rotateZ(50f);  
    camera.getMatrix(mMatrix);  
    camera.restore();  

    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),  
    bmp.getHeight(), mMatrix, true);  

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: very good answer, but if i want to visualize this rotation as animation ?

Comment: For animation, you don't need all these as you can easily use Android Animation Framework to animate a `View`. You don't need to get a `Bitmap` and use `Camera` to transform and (re)write the `Bitmap` into `ImageView`. Writing into a `Canvas` may justify this approach explained here but not for interacting with a `View`. What you really need is to add the drawable to an ImageView and apply animation to it.